# Time-series prediction/forecast coupled with classification

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm, multiclass-classification, prediction

I am trying to predict a danger zone.

I have a multidimensional time-series data and I want to forecast two timeseries for a defined number of time points. Then, I want to classify my predictions and see whether there will be a certain pattern that is medically dangerous.

Therefore, I am not sure "how to prepare my data optimally such that the prediction is the most accurate" and I guess there are different methods of preparation depending on the factors such as range of prediction vs overall accuracy.

Currently I am using Keras with Tensorflow.

Comment: Is the only reason you are forecasting so that  you can classify?

Comment: No. I am trying to classify the forecast. In an application the model is supposed to predict future events over a timespan and I want it to look ahead for dangerous patterns.